# Show ellipsis based on available height of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two divs "div1" and "div2" in a parent div. div 1 collides with div2. when that happens I want the text in div1 to break the words, occupy space till top of div2 and then show ellipsis.

I am able to find if the divs are colliding: http://jsfiddle.net/nGRwt/327/

```
function collision($div1, $div2) {
  var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
  var y1 = $div1.offset().top;
  var h1 = $div1.outerHeight(true);
  var w1 = $div1.outerWidth(true);
  var b1 = y1 + h1;
  var r1 = x1 + w1;
  var x2 = $div2.offset().left;
  var y2 = $div2.offset().top;
  var h2 = $div2.outerHeight(true);
  var w2 = $div2.outerWidth(true);
  var b2 = y2 + h2;
  var r2 = x2 + w2;

  if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
  return true;
}
```

[image]

I want above image to change as:

[image]

I think I have to calculate the remaining height of the div1 set the height using css and then apply ellipsis using javascript. But I am bad at calculations and not success to achieve above like in image 2.

How to achieve: making the text using available space and then to show ellipsis.

Comment: Multi-line truncation is not possible in CSS only so far. You can use jQuery plugin to achieve you want http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/ is one of the referance plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:-

```
#div1 {
width: 200px;
height: 43px;
background-color: pink;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
-webkit-line-clamp: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your #div1, kindly update your css

```
#div1 { 
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px; /* You can specify whatever you want */
    background-color: pink; 
    white-space: normal;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

For collision function

```
function collision() {
    $("#div1").css("height", $("#div1").height() + ($("#div2").height() - $("#div1").height()));
}
```

HTML, kindly remove

```
br element
```

Comment: I know above one. But I don't want to specify the width and height in css. I want to update css based on calculation in js file dynamically. like function calculateTruncation(el) {
    var text;
    while(el.clientHeight < el.scrollHeight) {
      text = el.innerHTML.trim();
      if(text.split(' ').length <= 1) {
        break;
      }
      el.innerHTML = text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
    }
  }